# What is best way to updating tree Panel

Tags: extjs, store, treepanel

I would like know , what is the best way to sync/load tree panel after updating database.
Today, i do an Ajax Request to make an updates. If the response is successful i use method load of my treeStore.

```
myTreePanel.getStore.load();
```

But this technic waste times . Maybe is not the best technic to do this ?!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if user updates a node & you commit changes to server/database you don't need to reload tree, just update that node `node.setText('BlahBlah')` but if it's more than one node or updates are comming from server & current user hasn't changed them (tree changes by other users & current user just sees changes) i would update UI with comming changes via websocket & if websockets wasn't possible i would fetch changes by doing ajax request every 20-30 seconds or so.

the thing i'm trying to say is it's better to change a small set of UI because it has better performance & DOM won't change so much, also you don't have to fetch all nodes, even those have not changed.